# Is There any Way to Predict Multi-Steps Ahead using a One-Step Predictor Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

As i Mentioned in Title,I have a Pre-Trained model,It Predicts one-step ahead.
How can I use it as a Multi-Step Ahead Predictor?
and will it Work Correctly?

This is How I Predict one-step ahead using x :

```
x = []
x.append(data[0:n,0])
x = np.array(x)
x = np.reshape(x,(x.shape[0] , x.shape[1],1))
y = model.predict(x)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is off-topic. In any case it is certainly too broad and vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are confident in your one-step predictor, you can use prediction from step n and feed it again through your predictor to get step n+1, then you can use the prediction for n+1 and feed it again through your predictor and so on until you get to  n+m where m is the number of steps you want predictions for. again your one-step predictor has to be very accurate and powerful to deliver on this task.

Comment: Val loss and loss both are a bit under 0.01. are they low enough?

Comment: I can't actually say if your model will work just from the loss value, you'll have to try the solution I suggested and experiment with retraining the model using the suggested approach and fine-tune its hyperparams to see if it will work for your task.